# My texture is doing weird, either not loaded correctly or not rendered correctly. DirectX11

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

I'm loading a texture from a file called owl.png. But it renders really weird.

Original picture(512 X 512):

[image]

But it renders like this:
[image]
It's rendered on a square, that is initialized like this:

```
 { XMFLOAT4(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0, 0), XMFLOAT2(0,1) },
 { XMFLOAT4(-0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 0),XMFLOAT2(0,0) },
 { XMFLOAT4(0.5f,  0.5f, 0, 0), XMFLOAT2(1,0) },
 { XMFLOAT4(0.5f,  -0.5f, 0, 0), XMFLOAT2(1, 1) }
```

Where the XMFLOAT2 are the tex coords.
It's loaded like this:

```
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* m_texture;
DirectX::CreateWICTextureFromFile(device, fileName, 0, &m_texture);
```

My samplerDesc looks like this:

```
samplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_ANISOTROPIC;
samplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
samplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
samplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
samplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 4;
```

And I use the normal sample method in my PS.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Instead of returning the sampled color value in the pixel shader, return the `uv`-coordinate directly.  It should look like [this](http://i.imgur.com/kQKiBM1.png).  If it doesn't, something's corrupting your input texture coordinates.

Comment: @MooseBoys It was a problem with my input layout, thanks.